# DocuSign custom button issue with Account name having apostrophe and/or Ampersand character

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

I have a button that I created for DocuSign within Salesforce but I'm having issues with it when the Account Name has the & symbol and/or it has an apostrophe in it. After researching this site, we found using the code below would get it to 'almost' work.  The subject showed up completely but it added the backslash next to the apostrophe.  Is there another way that I can get this to work?

**CODE**:

```
CES = 'Agreement for: {!URLENCODE(JSENCODE( Opportunity.Acct_Name_for_DocuSign__c ))}';
```

**What the subject actually has**:  Agreement for: Cheri\'s Bar & Grille

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of your code, the `JSENCODE` may not be necessary. That function escapes certain characters, such as `'`, with a `\` in front of them.